# Jquery Load Subcategory on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

can any explain which type of database needs to be created to run this code.
pls confirm the format of data

```
jQuery(".book-cat").click(
  function() {
    var book = jQuery(this).attr("book-cat");
    var node = '#book-cat-' + book;
    jQuery(node).toggle("slow");
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/book/info/' + book,
        cache: true
      })
      .done(function(html) {
        jQuery(node).html(html);
      });
  }
);
```

Comment: any kind of database :)
one to many relation.

Comment: Like, SQL, XML, or jSON

Comment: It doesn't matter the database type. you could achieve this functionality from any kind of database.